# What is the meaning of 确定 in 你确定你是外国人?

Tags: translation, meaning, meaning-in-context

I was told this sentence:

> 你确定你是外国人→_→

When I looked up the meaning of 确定 it said it meant definite/certain. So, my guess for this sentence is:

> Are you certain you are a foreigner/are you definitely a foreigner?

Am I right? Why was 确定 used in this context? What is its actual meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; in this context, 确定 means "to be certain".  It looks like someone is jokingly doubting that you are a foreigner.

Comment: It is correct that in this context, the speaker is using 确定 (to determine) to express " be certain", but it is better to say 肯定

Answer (score 2):

確定 as a verb means "to determine"

「**確定**你是外國人」literally means "**determined** you are a foreigner"

To illustrate the meaning of 「確定」 as a verb more clearly, let's look at the following sentences:

「可以**確定**這是假貨」( can **determine** this is a fake)

「可以**肯定**這是假貨」( can **be certain** that this is a fake)

「名單已被**確定**」( the list has been **determined**)

「名單已被**確認**」(the list has been **confirmed**)

"**Are** you **certain** you are a foreigner?" -「你**肯定**你是外國人?」